# Is a Windows Vista to 7 Upgrade like a clean install?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, upgrade

Is a Windows Vista to 7 Upgrade like a clean install?  What I mean is, if I do an in-place upgrade, will it act like a clean installation of Windows 7 with all my programs, docs, etc?  Or will it still have junk info/data left-over from Vista?

Comment: FWIW, the Vista-to-7 upgrade went smoother than any other Windows upgrade I've seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upgrade to Windows 7, it will typically do an in place upgrade and keep all documents and programs installed where you left them and just upgrade the version of Windows.

Answer (score 4):

> Is a Windows Vista to 7 Upgrade like a
>   clean install?

no, an in-place upgrade is not like a clean installation.

> will it still have junk info/data
>   left-over from Vista?

yes, but you can opt for a clean installation as explained in this tutorial:

**[Clean Install Windows 7 With Upgrade Media and Product Key on Formatted or Empty Blank Hard Drive](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/10/27/clean-install-windows-7-with-upgrade-media-and-product-key-on-formatted-or-empty-blank-hard-drive/)**

in this case you will have to backup/restore personal data and reinstall your programs.

Windows Setup does not differenciate between your "programs, docs, etc." and "junk info/data left-over from Vista".

Answer (score 2):

No, it can't.
I was using XP and have upgraded to 7 recently.
It should be clean install right? But my documents and program files are still there in C:\Windows.old
You have to delete that folder manually.

Comment: so, if I do a clean install on top of Vista, it will move everything to C:\Windows.old?  Or does it just do that in certain circumstances?

Comment: I am not very sure about it. The installer just told me his is going to do a clean install as Win 7 could not be upgraded from XP.

Answer (score 1):

By definition an in place upgrade is not like a clean install. An upgrade will allow you to maintain your programs, documents, data, etc. but will also leave whatever junk exists in place also.